# Word for loss function except weight regularization?

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, terminology, loss-functions

A typical loss function in machine learning is:

$$L(\theta,x) = \mathcal L(\theta,x) +\sum_{\theta} |\theta|$$

I typically use the word “loss function” both for $L(\theta,x)$ and for $\mathcal L(\theta,x)$.

What terminology is there to distinguish these?

- How do I refer to $L(\theta,x)$?
- how do I refer to $\mathcal L(\theta,x) $?

Answer (score 3):

I don't recall any specific name for the *regularized loss function*, people usually use this descriptive name. *Loss function* measures the error for a single sample, *cost function* measures it over all the data. The general name for the thing you optimize is called *objective function*, but if you want to be precise, better explicitly say that it is a regularized loss (or cost, they are often used interchangeably).

$$
 \DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min} \argmin_\theta \;\underbrace{\underbrace{\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \overbrace{\mathcal L(\theta,x_i)}^\text{loss function}}_\text{cost function} + \underbrace{\|\,\theta\,\|}_\text{regularization term}}_\text{objective function}
$$

See [Objective function, cost function, loss function: are they the same thing?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/179026/objective-function-cost-function-loss-function-are-they-the-same-thing)

Comment: What if you have multiple cost functions contributing to an aggregate cost function? What would you use for names then? I just asked this same question over at [Name for aggregate and component cost functions?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/406150/name-for-aggregate-and-component-cost-functions)