# Name for aggregate and component cost functions?

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, terminology, loss-functions

I was really thrilled to find a clear answer to [Word for loss function except weight regularization?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) But I'm in a situation where we have multiple costs functions in the objective function. We multiply each with a weight and sum all of them to produce an aggregate cost function.

What would you call these component cost functions and aggregate cost function?

My proposal:

- *category cost*
- *cost*

I like maintaining *cost* as the name for the outermost cost. I also like leaving *cost* in the name for the component costs as *category costs* since they are indeed costs on their own.

Any better proposals out there?