# Meaning of vertical bar | in loss function?

Tags: loss-functions, notation

Does anyone know what the vertical bars in these equations [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/179026/objective-function-cost-function-loss-function-are-they-the-same-thing?newreg=51754244c29342b78702e9c930049732) mean?

Specifically, these?

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It denotes that the function is parameterized by $\theta$ and the $x_i$ are the inputs to the function. For example $f(x|\theta)=x\cdot \theta$ is the dot product of the input, $x$, and the parameters $\theta$. User @Underminer adds a note about reading: if you wanted to read the symbols $f(x|\theta)$ aloud, you might say "the function $f$ of $x$ given $\theta$."

Some other usages are described at Wikipedia's article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_bar#Mathematics. Incidentally, this was my first Google hit for the search `math vertical bar notation`.

Comment: Nice succinct answer.  Also want to add that it is generally read as "given", as in "the function of x given theta".

Comment: Sometimes this is also read as "f of x conditional on $\theta$".

In traditional statistics sometimes there is another notation $f(x;\theta)$ which is always "f of x given $\theta$", as $\theta$ is not a random variable, but in Bayesian statistics, and sometimes machine learning, it is considered a random variable, hence "conditional upon" or "conditioned on".